# How to look up identical column names in two dataframes and combine the matched columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to loop trough column names of two data frames, find the columns with identical column name, and combine them to create a new data frame.

I tried to write an if-else condition in a for loop but it doesn't work.

To be specific, I have two data frame like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'2019Q1': 1, '2019Q2': 2, '2019Q3': 3},
                'B': {'2019Q1': 1, '2019Q2': 3, '2019Q3': 5},
                'C': {'2019Q1': 2, '2019Q2': 4, '2019Q3': 6}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'2019Q1': 4, '2019Q2': 5, '2019Q3': 6},
                'B': {'2019Q1': 1.5, '2019Q2': 3.3, '2019Q3': 5.6},
                'C': {'2019Q1': 2.3, '2019Q2': 4.8, '2019Q3': 6.7}})
```

I want outputs like below-

for A, output=

```
pd.DataFrame({'df1': {'2019Q1': 1, '2019Q2': 2, '2019Q3': 3},
              'df2': {'2019Q1': 4, '2019Q2': 5, '2019Q3': 6})
```

for B, output=

```
pd.DataFrame({'df1': {'2019Q1': 1, '2019Q2': 3, '2019Q3': 5},
              'df2': {'2019Q1': 1.5, '2019Q2': 3.3, '2019Q3': 5.6})
```

for C,output=

```
pd.DataFrame({'df1': {'2019Q1': 2, '2019Q2': 4, '2019Q3': 6},
              'df2': {'2019Q1': 2.3, '2019Q2': 4.8, '2019Q3': 6.7})
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way similar to @ALollz but save the subdf in multiple index dataframe

```
s = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2']).unstack(0)
s.loc[:,'A']
Out[390]: 
        df1  df2
2019Q1    1    4
2019Q2    2    5
2019Q3    3    6
```

Answer (score 3):

`concat` with keys + `groupby`. Store the results in a dict, with the columns as keys.

```
d = {idx: gp.droplevel(1, axis=1) for idx, gp in
     pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2'], axis=1).groupby(level=1, axis=1)}

d['A']
#        df1  df2
#2019Q1    1    4
#2019Q2    2    5
#2019Q3    3    6

d['B']
#        df1  df2
#2019Q1    1  1.5
#2019Q2    3  3.3
#2019Q3    5  5.6
```

---

The above will create Frames for all columns regardless if they're found in both. If that's not useful you can change the concat to:

```
cols = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)
pd.concat([df1[cols], df2[cols]], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both dataframes are indexed by quarter, you can `merge` them:

```
for col in np.union1d(df1.columns, df2.columns):
    result = df1[[col]].merge(df2[[col]], how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    result.index.name = col
    result.columns = ['df1', 'df2']
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
        df1  df2
A               
2019Q1    1    4
2019Q2    2    5
2019Q3    3    6

        df1  df2
B               
2019Q1    1  1.5
2019Q2    3  3.3
2019Q3    5  5.6

        df1  df2
C               
2019Q1    2  2.3
2019Q2    4  4.8
2019Q3    6  6.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar logic you did, by (1) looping through the columns and (2) passing them to a new dataframe if they exist in both `df`. You can store the results in a dictionary, where the key is the column name:

```py
for col in all_cols:
    if col in df1.columns and col in df2.columns:
        final_df[col] = pd.DataFrame({'df1': df1[col].values, 'df2': df2[col].values})

final_df['A']
    df1     df2
0   1       4
1   2       5
2   3       6

final_df['B']
    df1     df2
0   1       1.5
1   3       3.3
2   5       5.6

final_df['C']
    df1     df2
0   2       2.3
1   4       4.8
2   6       6.7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in df1:
    if column in df2:
        df = pd.DataFrame({"df1": df1[column].values, "df2": df2[column].values})
```

Comment: You forgot to check if the column exists in the other dataframe. It's not always necessary